# Expand a 2D array into a 3D array with specific length

Tags: python, numpy, dimensions

I have a 100x100 numpy array that I want to add for it a third dimension which has length 3 which have [1,0,1].
I'm trying to do this without a for loop if possible. 
Tried all sort of things like np.newaxis but it only expands the dimension with length 1 and then it can't be populated with a array of length 3.

Thank yiu

Comment: What exactly is [1,0,1]?

Comment: Just an array of 3 numbers. It doesn't matter much.

Comment: It matters because you did not explain their purpose. Do you want to overwrite the original array data and have a plane of ones, a plane of zeros, and another plane of ones? Or do you want to add three _more_ planes?

Comment: I want to add three more planes. I am better understanding myself:)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want you have a few options:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((100, 100))
some_numbers = [1, 0, 1]

# A
new_arr = np.empty(arr.shape + (3,))
new_arr[..., :] = some_numbers
# array([[[1., 0., 1.],
#         [1., 0., 1.],
#         [1., 0., 1.], 
#         ...,

# A2
new_arr = np.empty(arr.shape + (len(some_numbers) + 1,))
new_arr[..., 0] = arr[..., np.newaxis]
new_arr[..., 1:] = some_numbers
# array([[[0.2853, 1., 0., 1.],
#         [0.7324, 1., 0., 1.],
#         [0.0706, 1., 0., 1.],
#         ...,

# B
new_arr = np.empty(arr.shape + (3,))
new_arr[..., :] = arr[..., np.newaxis]

# C
new_arr = np.repeat(arr[..., np.newaxis], 3, axis=-1)
# array([[[0.2853, 0.2853, 0.2853],
#         [0.7324, 0.7324, 0.7324],
#         [0.0706, 0.0706, 0.0706],
#         ...,
```

- In `case A` you are overwriting all elements of arr with `[1, 0, 1]`.
- In `case A2` you keep the original array at `new_arr[:, :, 0]` and fill the remaining planes `new_arr[:, :, 1:]`  with `some_numbers` respectively.
- In `case B` and `case C` you repeat the `100x100` array 3 times along the new third dimension.

Comment: Thank you but that's not quite what I need. Neither A nor B and C. I don't want to replace everything. Or repeat the 2d in 3d. I want the third dimension to be other set of three numbers

Comment: and what numbers? just three numbers? or 3 different `(100 x 100)` arrays? Could you state clearly what you want to achieve, preferable with an example.

Comment: Ok. Its obvious I wasn't clear. I want to expand the 2D array into 3 planes and then populatet each plane with some number. So I think @valdi_bo is almost what I need

Comment: Ok, but I am still a little bit confused. Is the case you describe not `case A` for `[some_num1, some_num2, some_num3]`  instead of `[1, 0, 1]` ?

Comment: I added a `case A2`, is this what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to generate a 3-D array:

- the first "layer" filled with ones,
- the second "layer" filled with zeroes,
- the third "layer" filled again with ones,
- all "layers" with dimension 100 * 100.

For readablity, I changed your assumptions:

- the third "layer" filled with *2*,
- all "layers" with dimension 5 * 5.

Step 1: Create each 2-D array (layer in the target array):

```
arr1 = np.ones((5,5), dtype=np.int)
arr2 = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.int)
arr3 = np.full((5,5), 2)
```

Step 2: Create the target array:

```
res = np.stack((arr1, arr2, arr3), axis=2)
```

When you print *res.shape*, you will get:

```
(5, 5, 3)
```

(5 rows, 5 columns, 3 layers)

To see each "layer" separately, run `res[:, :, n]` where *n* is either
*0*, *1* or *2*. E.g. for *n == 2* (the last layer) I got:

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```